# Portals and communities

Tags: community, portal

Can any one give me an example business scenario where I should implement portals 
What is the difference between a Partner Portal and a Customer Portal? And some idea about the licenses and how much they cost.

I see that they are now replaced by Communities, any example scenario on when I need to implement Portal/community is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Portals are no longer sold by Salesforce; you would be looking at Communities.

The scenarios where Communities are useful are where you want to expose/share portions of your SFDC data with your partners or customers, but don't want to grant/pay for full SFDC access. There are limitations on the number and types of objects you can share with them.

Your salesforce rep can give you cost numbers; they are a fraction of standard license fees.